# Как определить строку, вызвавшую Exception в Python 2.x?

Tags: python, исключения

Код выглядит так:

```
try:
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
exception Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```

Периодически в try секции происходят различные исключения, я их прекрасно вижу print str(e), но непонятно, в какой строке оно произошло. Есть ли метод определения не только текста исключения, но и строки кода, которая его вызвала?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Есть модуль [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html). Пример:

```
import traceback

def f():
    raise Exception('hello')

try:
    f()
except Exception, e:
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

выводит:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    f()
  File "test.py", line 5, in f
    raise Exception('hello')
Exception: hello
```

Answer (score 1):

В trace back линия с ошибкой показана

http://www.warayg.narod.ru/context/prog/Python/python10.htm

Comment: блин, пака я тормоз писал меня выше опередили =)

Answer (score 1):

Поисковки по запросу "вывести номер строки(или текст) кода который привёл к исключению" ведут сюда, поэтому я выложу ответ для 3.X Python.
Подобный декоратор позволяет не останавливать работу программы, а выводить, что при выполнении были исключения.

```
import traceback as tr
def log(f, *sfaf):
    def wrapper(*arg,**kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*arg,**kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            error = tr.TracebackException(exc_type =type(e),exc_traceback = e.__traceback__ , exc_value =e).stack[-1]
            print('{} in {} row:{} | arguments:{}'.format(e,
                error.lineno,
                error.line,
                (arg,kwargs)
            ))
    return wrapper

@log
def asd(x=0):
    result = x/2
    return result

asd(x='2')
```